# How to setText to multiple selected Items from a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Can somebody tell me how can I display in a TextView multiple selected items from a ListView?
I want to display only items which are selected, when item is unselected it can't be displayed.
Here's my code

```
final String[] favoriteTVShows =
            {
                    "Wolf", "Inception", "Heat", "Gladiator", "Birdman", "Seven", "TVshow1", "TVshow2", "Tvshow3"
            };

    ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, favoriteTVShows);

    ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);

    theListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    theListView.setItemChecked(2, true);


    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);




    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String tvShowPicked = "You selected " + String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));

            Toast.makeText(List.this, tvShowPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a method to update the text view text every time onItemClick is called.

   void updateTextView() {
       ...
   }
2. Use getCheckedItemPositions to get an array of checked items in your list and add it your method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions()
3. Use a StringBuilder to add the labels for selected items inside the method:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems; i++) {
       sb.append(selectedItems[i]);
       if (i < selectedItems.length - 1) {
           sb.append(", "); // Add a comma for separation
       }
   }
   textView.setText(sb);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't know how to do this method right, because public SparseBooleanArray getCheckedItemPositions(position); can't be used, maybe I need to put something else in position?

Comment: getCheckedItemPositions does not take an integer parameter, instead it returns a SparseBooleanArray which you can use to check which positions have their values checked. You can iterate over this set and build your string that way.